# How to fix makefile to properly include -lcrypto to avoid linker error: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'

Tags: c++, makefile, openssl

First of all I am trying to use

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

I am getting the common linker error:

```
undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
```

which I know can be solved by using `-lcrypto` when compiling. I am able to do this when compiling manually i.e

```
g++ encrv2.cpp -o encrv2 -lcrypto
```

though I am trying to create a Makefile and putting my encryption/decryption functions in a seperate header file (AesGcm) and am unable to get around the linker issue. Below is my Makefile so far and the output when I try and make all.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14
LDFLAGS= -lcrypto

all: encrv2

AesGcm.o: AesGcm.cpp AesGcm.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c AesGcm.cpp $(LDFLAGS)

encrv2.o: encrv2.cpp AesGcm.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c encrv2.cpp $(LDFLAGS)

encrv2: encrv2.o AesGcm.o

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o encrv2
```

Giving the following error:

```
cc -lcrypto  encrv2.o AesGcm.o   -o encrv2
AesGcm.o: In function `AesGcm::encrypt(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char*, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)':
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_gcm'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptUpdate'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptUpdate'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x197): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
AesGcm.o: In function `AesGcm::decrypt(unsigned char*, int, unsigned char*, int, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*)':
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x30a): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_256_gcm'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptInit_ex'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x37a): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptInit_ex'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x3ac): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptUpdate'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x3dd): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptUpdate'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x410): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x441): undefined reference to `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex'
AesGcm.cpp:(.text+0x450): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'encrv2' failed
make: *** [encrv2] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong variable.

`LDFLAGS` are intended to be used for linker flags such as `-L`, etc. that need to come "earlier" in the link line.  That variable is not intended to have libraries that are added to the link line.

You should be using the `LDLIBS` variable for that:

```
LDLIBS = -lcrypto
```

The default rule for linking, which is what you're using since you don't write one yourself, looks something like this:

```
%: %.o
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Note that `LDLIBS` comes *after* your object files, which is what you need to avoid this linker error.  Order of object files versus libraries, and between libraries themselves, is very important to the linker.

Comment: I actually did not know there was a default rule for linking, I was looking at the OPs makefile and asking myself how does it even attempt to link, thanks:D